# YandexMapKit 3, как вывести статическую карту?

Tags: android, yandex-maps-api, yandexmapkit, yandex-static-maps-api

Как в новой версии MapKit на Android вывести статическую карту вроде [такой](https://static-maps.yandex.ru/1.x/?pt=53.288440,56.862563,pm2am~53.264922,56.877430,ya_ru&l=map,trf&size=400,400)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Разобрался с проблемой.

[StaticAPI](https://static-maps.yandex.ru/1.x/?ll=37.620070,55.753630&size=450,450&z=13&l=map&pt=37.620070,55.753630,pmwtm1~37.64,55.76363,pmwtm99) выдаёт обычное изображение, которое затем можно благодаря библиотекам работы с изображениями вставлять в приложение.

Answer (score 1):

[Технические вопросы](https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/doc/mapkit/3.x/concepts/faq-docpage/)

> **Есть ли в MapKit возможность создать статическую карту?**
>
> В MapKit есть возможность отключить пользовательское взаимодействие с
>   картой с помощью метода [setNoninteractive](https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/doc/mapkit/3.x/concepts/android/mapkit/ref/com/yandex/mapkit/mapview/MapView-docpage/#method_detail__method_setNoninteractive__boolean) для Android...